# Why is my JS/DOM code displaying no content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My test</title>
<style>

    .img {
            display:inline-block;
            border:dotted;
        }
        .button {
            display:inline-block;
            border:dotted;
        }
</style>
<script>
    //Loads all the elements and assigns event handlers
    function load()
    {
        var root = document.getElementById("body");

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "button");
        test.setAttribute("id", "p");
        test.innerHTML = "Prev"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anne"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anise"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anna"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "button");
        test.setAttribute("id", "n");
        test.innerHTML = "Next"
        root.appendChild(test);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false)
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't produce anything on the page! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a DOM element with the `id` attribute of `body`, when you really intend to get the body tag.

```
// Instead of
var root = document.getElementById("body");

// Try:
var root = document.body;
```

You could also add an id attribute to the `<body>` tag as `<body id='body'>` without having to modify your JavaScript, but this seems kind of inappropriate. Modify your script to use `document.body` instead.

#### Update

You are overwriting the `innerHTML` property of `btnPrev` in each group of lines.  We don't see where `btnPrev` is even defined in your markup.  Perhaps each time you define `var test`, you intend to define `btnPrev`?

Comment: Great, however, all I am seeing now is the last thing added. "Next"

Comment: @antonpug  `btnPrev` doesn't appear to exist anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this through IE debugger I got: 'btnPrev' is undefined.

Comment: It will likely fail in IE though...because it's IE?

Comment: Failed in Firefox also...btnPrev is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of variables used in load() function. You are storing DOM references into `test` variable but (`test`) it is not used to set attribute values.

```
 var btnPrev = document.createElement("div");
 btnPrev.setAttribute("class", "button");
 btnPrev.setAttribute("id", "p");
 btnPrev.innerHTML = "Prev"
 root.appendChild(btnPrev);
```

EDIT:

```
 function load()
    {
        var root = document.body;
        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "button");
        test.setAttribute("id", "p");
        test.innerHTML = "Prev"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anne"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anise"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "main");
        test.innerHTML = "Anna"
        root.appendChild(test);

        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.setAttribute("class", "button");
        test.setAttribute("id", "n");
        test.innerHTML = "Next"
        root.appendChild(test);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following change is all I needed to your (updated) code to get it to work in Firefox:

```
var root = document.body;
```

(Or assign an ID to the body element, either way worked.)

After that, the question becomes "Which browser are you testing with?"

It won't work in IE before version 9 because older IE versions don't support `.addEventListener()` or the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

The following worked for me in IE7 (the only version of IE I have to test with):

```
if (document.addEventListener)
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent('onload',load);
else
  window.onload = load;
```